# Clear Input field on show / hide | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to clear the Home Number field when a user clicks on another option within the options list.

Currently if you were to select Option 3, home number displays - this is good. If you are to select Option 1 whilst Option 3 is displayed mobile number shows. This is good too however, my validation bombs because Home Number is required and expects it to be filled out even though the input isn't shown on the page.

My thoughts to get around this would be to clear the Home Number input if another selection has been made? This could be wrong but I'm unsure of another solution to get around this.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn2fJ/92/)

Here is my jQuery:

```
var form = {

    init: function () {
        form.selection();

    },

    selection: function () {
        var homeNumber = $('.home-number'),
            mobileNumber = $('.mobile-number');

        $("li.checkbox").on('click', function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).find("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) $(this).addClass("active");
            else $(this).removeClass("active");
            //If all three are selected show mobile, hide home
            if ($("ul li.checkbox.active").length > 1) {
                mobileNumber.css('display', 'block');
                homeNumber.val('');
                homeNumber.hide();
            } else if ($("li.last-option").hasClass("active")) {
                //If select last option only show home
                homeNumber.toggleClass('home-active');
                homeNumber.show();
                mobileNumber.hide();
                //If select last option only hide mobile
                mobileNumber.toggleClass('mobile-inactive');

            } else {
                homeNumber.val('');
                homeNumber.hide();
                mobileNumber.show();
            }



        });
    }
}
$(function () {
    form.init();
});
```

Comment: Well it depends on how your validation works?  Some are class-based e.g. have a class `required` or similar.  If that's the case you can just `addClass` and `removeClass` as needed.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when your question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: When you're checking whether the home number or mobile number is filled out, make sure it's visible too - problem solved.

Comment: What validation are you using such that it "bombs."  If it's a framework or plugin, there's probably a setting to ignore non-visible fields.

Comment: Validation I'm using is jquery validate.

Comment: within my rule I have required: true and I am using the visible attribute yet it's not working for that instance unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly you want? your question is not much clear like you want to clear the field or you want to disable the validation? When you are validating the field... Thanks

Comment: I'm wanting the home validation to not throw an exception in the case provided in the question. Please read again as it is clearly outlined.